# Trying to create a Nextra page on my Next Js project

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to create a Nextra page inside my Nextjs project and I am doing the process manually since I am implementing this on something that is already done. But every time I create a page with .md extension I get a blank page with this code write on it:

```
import withLayout from 'nextra-theme-blog' import { withSSG } from 'nextra/ssg' import layoutConfig from '/Users/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/theme.config.js'

export default function NextraPage (props) { return withSSG(withLayout({ filename: "test.md", route: "/test", meta: {}, pageMap: [{"name":"test","route":"/test"}] }, layoutConfig))(props) }
```

Could someone help me with why is this happening? Or give me another plugin that could offer a similar solution?

Note 1: I am using Chakra UI and Next Js.

Note 2: I am trying to create a simple "docs" page on my website, just like in this example:

https://nextra.vercel.app/